# Send SMS through PhoneGap on Android

Tags: android, sms, contacts, cordova

I am exploring capabilities and features of PhoneGap. I have gone through the [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/about/) site. Is there any possibility (or) workaround to send text messages and access phonebook information of Android using the PhoneGap framework?

Comment: It looks like phonegap's SMS class has been deprecated. Any workarounds for sending sms to multiple recipients? Note: would have commented but don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/5cf45fcade4989668e95a6d34630d2021c45291a/Android/SMSPlugin Have you tried to use this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes on both accounts. There are [Contacts](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/JavaScript-API#contacts) and [SMS](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/JavaScript-API#sms) classes as part of the [Javascript API](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/JavaScript-API).

Comment: Hmm I see that they are working on it from the road map: http://wiki.phonegap.com/Roadmap is this outdated?

Comment: NOTE:  This page is obsolete.  The most recent documentation is available at http://docs.phonegap.com.

Answer (score 8):

The function is outdated.

But Plugins will get it work:

- [SMS inbox_sent_access](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMS%20inbox_sent%20access) (Android)
- [SMSComposer Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer) (iPhone)

According to the [Roadmap planing](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/28291160/roadmap-planning), Phonegap will add a messaging API in summer 2012.

Comment: SMS inbox_sent_access doesn't provide capability to send sms but answer still useful

Comment: The one that provides capability to send is :  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin

Comment: @DanielBenedykt link is 404

Answer (score 1):

You can also write phonegap plugins to achieve functions on top of phonegap (e.g. send SMS).

See the github project https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins.

Basically the crux of it is that you can write native android (or other platform) code with inside the plugin, register that plugin with the phonegap plugin manager and then youll have access to all APIs (e.g. SMSManager) :-)

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.3, also check this: https://github.com/dimitrismistriotis/SendSmsCordovaPlugin, MIT liscnse. (Disclaimer: Written by me).