# Crossplatform mobile app dev environment for reading SMS inbox

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, sms

Is there a **cross-platform mobile app dev environment** that allow us to access the SMS inbox of the phone?

I would like to create messenger apps on different platforms(Android and Symbian at least) that plays around with SMS. I learnt that [Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193997/send-sms-through-phonegap-on-android) and [Mosync](http://www.mosync.com/content/receive-sms) is currently not providing such API, and I am still finding it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

MoSync allows you to send SMS, but like you say, it wont let you receive them.
I guess the reason is, most app only need to send sms, because incoming messages
can be picked up from a server. Also many apps use sms to generate spread/users,
once your app is connected to a IP service of some kind you just talk to the server.
There is of course the cost question, send sms costs app users money, receiving sms
can cost the service provider money.