# How to send text message in phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, cordova

I am developing one app in phonegap.
In my app i am using one text field which contains some text  and one
button for sending text.When i will click on button then one alert box
should open .Which contains three button "SMS","CHAT","Cancel".when i
will  click on SMS button then my message should be send via sms.When
i will click on chat button then my message should be sent via chat.
How is  it possible .Is there anyone have any demo or idea then pls
reply for my post .I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Try out the stuff in the answers, may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193997/send-sms-through-phonegap-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct support in the phonegap api for what you are trying to do, but you can write your own phonegap plugin to achieve what you want.

There is a SMS Composer Plugin, which should be a good starting point for what you are trying to create: https://github.com/grantsanders/SMSComposer

**Updated**: here are two SMS plugins, since the above plugin is 404ing

Android: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin
iOS: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/SMSComposer

Answer (score 2):

The link by Daniel is now broken.

However I found this website full of PhoneGap plugins: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins