# how can we integrate sms gateway in sencha touch 2.0?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, sms-gateway

Hello friends i am working on phonegap with sencha touch 2.0 app in which i have to integrate sms gateway. Can anyone explain me with some example how to achieve this?

**Edit:-**

I have gone through the following links and dont find it helpful because the link provided phonegap's SMS class link but now its deprecated.

[SMS from sencha touch app](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131445-It-is-possible-to-send-SMS-Messages-from-a-Sencha-Touch-App)

[Send SMS through PhoneGap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193997/send-sms-through-phonegap-on-android)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Look at the related questions.

Comment: if related question is available then give me the link.....

Comment: I have gone through this link and dont find it helpful because the link provided phonegap's SMS class link and now its deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , It worked for me

```
{
  xtype: 'button',
                       flex: 1,
                        ui: 'action',
                        text: 'SMS',
                        id: 'smsButton',
                        handler: function () {
                            window.location = 'sms:xxxxxxx';
                        }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this method will open up a sms window? or would it just send the sms without showing the sms editor??